# Odoo many2many_kanban widget is not showing the delete (X) button

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

This is my XML Code, the many2many_kanban view is not showing the X button to delete.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="crm_customer_form_view_leads_inherited">
           <field name="name">res.partner.form.inherit</field>
           <field name="model">res.partner</field>
           <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
              <field name="arch" type="xml">
                 <xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page[@name='internal_notes']" position="after">
                     <page name="Employees" string="Empolyees">
                        <field name="employee_ids" widget="many2many_kanban"/>
                    </page>
                </xpath>
               </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: Have u check that current logged in user access right for that hr.employee model ?

Comment: I logged in as an Admin user

Comment: then check the admin has to access the hr.employee model It means read access

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how kanban widget looks like in Team Members (view_id : `sales_team.crm_team_view_form` )

```
<field name="member_ids" widget="many2many_kanban">
<kanban quick_create="false" create="true" delete="true">
    <field name="name"/>
    <templates>
        <t t-name="kanban-box">
            <div class="oe_kanban_global_click" style="position: relative">
                <a t-if="! read_only_mode" type="delete" style="position: absolute; right: 0; padding: 4px; diplay: inline-block">X</a>
                <div class="oe_module_vignette">
                    <img t-att-src="kanban_image('res.users', 'image_small', record.id.value)" class="oe_avatar oe_kanban_avatar_smallbox"/>
                    <div class="oe_module_desc">
                        <field name="name"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </t>
    </templates>
</kanban>
</field>
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much mokiSRB. You saved my time. Now it works fine. Thanks again.